# How to print a sentence pulling information from a dictionary that has a dictionary inside

Tags: python, dictionary

I am quite new to Python and I am struggling with a simple code that creates dictionaries and tries to print the information inside it.
I created a dictionary named pets that contains the name of the pets as keys. The values are dictionaries that contain pieces of information about the pets.

I want to print in one sentence the name of the pet, and the information about the pet.

As shown in my code below, I am trying to create a for loop that will print a sentence for each pet.

```
pets = {
    'maxi': {
    'owner':'Laura',
     'favorite food':'wiskas'
    },
    'chester': {
    'owner':'Emilia',
    'favorite food':'lula'
        }
    }

print(pets)
for name,info in pets.items():
    print(name + "'s owner and favorite food are " + name['owner'] + ' and ' + name['favorite food'])
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pets.py", line 14, in
>   
>       print(name + "'s owner and favorite food are " + name['owner'] + ' and ' + name ['favorite food']) 
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `for name,info in pets.items()` loop, `name` is actually a string. That's why you get that error: you're trying to access the elements of a string.
You need to use `info` to access the internal values:

```
for name, info in pets.items():
    print(name + '\'s owner and favorite food are ' + info['owner'] + ' and ' + info['favorite food'])
```

Comment: plese consider accepting this as an answer if I answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for x in pets:
    print(x + "'s owner and favorite food are " + pets[x]['owner'] + ' ' + pets[x]['favorite food'])    

>>> maxi's owner and favorite food are Laura wiskas
>>> chester's owner and favorite food are Emilia lula
```

your mistake was "name['owner'] + ' and ' + name['favorite food']" <- this
since you have to refer first to the item in dict, in our case "x" or "name" call it whatever you want, then you want to enter his key to take its name, so, pets[name]['owner'] same goes for the food except you take the other key, in our case "favorite food", i hope this clears something for you :D